# C# asp.net project functionalities

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, project

I just started working in a project that wasn't developed by me, and I'm worrying about some functionalities, and I would like a suggestion from the people I always count! You Guys!

After the login validations, the login procedure is made like this:

```
var _ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.ID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), true, user.ID);

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(_ticket);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

As we can see, there is a user object which stores every info of the logged in user (Id, name, e-mail...)

The first problem that I see is that on the FormsAuthenticationTicket the user ID is passed as the name. And everytime I want to get any info from the user I have to do this:

```
Item user = Framework.Business.Item.Load(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

The project uses master page, and on everypage I have to do this to get (ID, name and picture) of the logged user

By the way, at least the load method gets the userdate from a collection, BUT, this collection stores not only the users data but everydata data that need to be cached (since ID's are GUIDs) ids won't be duplicated and I think because os this reason, there is only one Collection for everything.

I would like to know if this is right, or what should I do to make it better

Comment: okay, so I read this 5 times and still do not understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I would like to know if this is right, or what should I do to make it better

Comment: If it's working it's right....Incase you are looking for code review, visit [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange)

Comment: oh it's working right. Sorry I didn't know there were an appropriate place. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's right. You don't need to worry about the code:

```
Item user = Framework.Business.Item.Load(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

It's OK. The HttpContext.Current.User is (must be indeed) initialized automatically in every request. That's it.

Comment: well, but doing that, I think I'm loading information that I dont need. Like gender, last name, etc... That's why I'm worrying about.
And all the data is stored in a collection not only the ser data, which makes me worry even... I know i could store the frenquety used data in a session, but I dont know if its right to do this way.